# Magento 2 : Add Custom Data From Product Page to Cart

Tags: magento2, product, cart, data

I have form on my product page where users can enter what they want their height to be. How can I send this data through to cart? I have created a row in quote_item table to save data in already.

Comment: You can simple create "Height" attribute and assigned it to attribute set.

Comment: The user says what they want their height to be, it doesn't want to be a product attribute, just one for the quote and attribute. It will be different for each order. @PrincePatel

Comment: If you have different for each product you can use custom option. @Tom

Comment: It's a form that calculates a price, but I just at the moment need to pass one field from the form into the cart @PrincePatel

Answer (score 1):

You need to create event for that:-

```
app/code/CompanyName/ModuleName/etc/frontend/event.xml file

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="checkout_cart_product_add_after">
        <observer name="cart_product" instance="CompanyName\ModuleName\Observer\CartProduct" />
    </event>
</config>
```

In observer file

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace CompanyName\ModuleName\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
class CartProduct implements ObserverInterface
{
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request)
{
  $this->_request = $request;
}
 public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
   {
      $height= $this->_request->getPost('height');
      $item = $observer->getQuoteItem();
      $item->setHeight($height);
      //if you want to add as custom option then 
        $item->addOption(
        array(
             'code'  => 'height',
             'value' => $height
        )
    ); 
   }
}
```

After that flush cache and check it.

Comment: It's a form that calculates a price, but I just at the moment need to pass one field from the form into the cart

Comment: if that not work then i will explain another way

Comment: what is the other way?

Comment: Thank you, and then how would I display the height in the cart?

Comment: if you want to show into cart without cart file modified then you need to add custom option progrmically.

Comment: is that work for you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58112/discussion-between-user3383912-and-tom).